# Cannot create instance of type 'Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Schedule.ScheduleAppointmentEditor'

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, syncfusion

I'm using WinRT C# application and after a Windows update 20H2 (framework: 528372), the syncfusion Scheduler component stopped working and crashes the application. On Windows 1909 (framework: 528040) it works correctly

The error: Cannot create instance of type 'Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Schedule.ScheduleAppointmentEditor'

I updated the libaries to a newer version which didn't solve my issue.

I currently have two versions of the same application

- WinRT
- UWP

The UWP works fine on 20H2 Windows versions and both UWP and WinRT apps have the same libaries for the syncfusion.

Any workaround that I can put in place to make it work again on version 20H2?

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion gave an updated library with the fix. Issue Resolved

Heres the link, version 14.4.0.15 but this is specific to this issue as i could read : https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/168937/cannot-create-instance-of-type-syncfusion-ui-xaml-schedule-scheduleappointmenteditor

Comment: For future readers, can you tell us what version includes the fix?

Comment: Heres the link, version 14.4.0.15 but this is specific to this issue as i could read : https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/168937/cannot-create-instance-of-type-syncfusion-ui-xaml-schedule-scheduleappointmenteditor

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Cannot create instance of type 'Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Schedule.ScheduleAppointmentEditor
The reported issue has been fixed and included in the patch which can be download from the below links.

Recommended approach - exe will perform automatic configuration.

Please find the patch setup from below location:
Patch link:
https://syncfusion.com/Installs/support/patch/14.4.0.15/1015043/F168937/SyncfusionPatch_14.4.0.15_1015043_9272021085339206_F168937.exe

Please find the patch assemblies alone from below location:
Assemblies Link: https://syncfusion.com/Installs/support/patch/14.4.0.15/1015043/F168937/SyncfusionPatch_14.4.0.15_1015043_9272021085339206_F168937.zip

Nuget link: https://syncfusion.com/Installs/support/patch/14.4.0.15/1015043/F168937/SyncfusionNuget_14.4.0.15_1015043_9272021085339206_F168937.zip

Disclaimer:
Please note that we have created this patch for version 14.4.0.15 specifically to resolve the issue reported in this incident.